# How the props of react.js are declared

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to React. I'm not understanding a part in [this code](https://gist.github.com/RyanAtViceSoftware/8312dcf44f5d583b3425):

```
var HelloMessage = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return <h2>{this.props.message}</h2>;
    }
});

var TextBox = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return { isEditing: false }
    },
    update: function() {
        // Where is props.update defined? //
        this.props.update(this.refs.messageTextBox.value);
        this.setState(
            {
                isEditing: false
            });
    },
    edit: function() {
        this.setState({ isEditing: true});
    },
```

In the code I can't find the `props` declaration for `update`. But looking through the code we should see "update" as a property of the TextBox component.

I'm not seeing an explicit declaration of `this.props.update` within any render method.

How/Where is `props.update` defined?

Comment: attribute and its value of component ( as JSX ) are keys and value of component ( as React Element )

Comment: Thanks i was able to figure out the origins of the attribute with your response

Comment: Hi! I edited your post to make it more readable, so you can get the help you need. I added in some code from your example. You should always include a [minimal working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your code along with any errors you're seeing. I understand you want to know more about the inner-workings of React, but if you don't post references such as those I mentioned, it is unlikely you will get help. Good Luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So inside the `HelloReact` component `render` method, a few `TextBox` components are returned like so:

```
...
<TextBox label='First Name' update={this.update.bind(null, 'firstName')}>
...
```

Now here what is happening is that `HelloReact` is passing a prop named `update` to this `TextBox` component. This means that inside the `TextBox` component I will be able to use this prop with `this.props.update`. Every prop that is passed down from the parent will populate `this.props` of the child. In this specific case we are passing down `label` and `update`.

Now inside the `TextBox` component we will be able to access these props intuitively with `this.props.label` and `this.props.update`. Inside this component it's define a private method that is called `update`, this is the code from the snippet you posted with better formatting:

```
...
update: function() {
  this.props.update(this.refs.messageTextBox.value);
  this.setState({ isEditing: false });
},
...
```

So here we are calling `this.props.update` which is the prop that was passed down from the parent in `HelloReact`. The reason we are wrapping this call in a private method is because on top of being able to call `this.props.update()` we also want to do something else, in this case we want to update the state of the `TextBox` component as well.

I hope this explanation was clear enough. I suggest reading about React from the official docs which are pretty amazing, or watch any of the many tutorials online. These are key concepts of React and you need to understand them properly in order to be able to develop in React.

For this case you might wanna read [this](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/components-and-props.html), which comes from the offical docs and is about props.